# What is the appropriate method for inserting intro screen for iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I've just complete Apple's tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1) and going to start my iOS project.

As I said above, I want to insert intro screen which appears at the first time and disappears after 3 seconds. So I created the View and, at func viewDidAppear() inside the View Controller, called sleep and performSegue function( segue with Show Detail ).

Here are my questions.

1. Is it proper way? ( I can't sure that the memory of intro view will be deallocated or not )
2. How can I use fade out animation? Do I have to make custom segue?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance.

Comment: "called sleep" Never sleep. Never.

Comment: Thanks matt. Can I ask you why?

Comment: Block main thread? Evil. User can't interact with screen. WatchDog process will come along and kill your app dead right before the user's eyes. Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

//                     Your code to hide the view
//                     for e.g.,
//                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
//                          self.dummyView.alpha = 0.0f;
//                    }];

                });
```